# How to check collision between the mouse and a sprite group

Tags: python, mouse, pygame, collision

I'm trying detect collision between the mouse and a sprite group. I have searched around for awhile but couldn't find anything about it. So if you know how to do this could you please explain how such a thing is done? If so I would greatly appreciate it. Also I'm not exactly sure which parts of code I would need to show you but if you need any please tell me what part of it you would need and I will post it.

Comment: What did you try? What framework are you using? You need to give us more details if you want for us to help you.

Comment: I haven't tried anything considering I don't know what to try. And what exactly do you mean by framework?

Comment: i.e. What are you using for your sprites? What library are you using for your sprites?

Comment: I'm using the pygame sprite library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using pygame, the easiest way is to create a Sprite that will not have a image, and the position will change with the mouse. To access the mouse coordinates use :

```
pygame.mouse.get_pos(): return (x, y)
```

then you can use your existing collision detection with this new Sprite.

Comment: `some_spite.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())`: -- Otherwise If you use the events `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` or `MOUSEMOTION` you get the coordinates when you click, or move.

Comment: Alright I have it creating a sprite that is supposed to be for the mouse. But I'm not really sure how to actually move the sprite. I tried using move_ip but that doesn't work. Any suggestions on what I should use to move the sprite?

Comment: You change sprite's `.rect` attribute. Make sure your class derives from `pygame.sprite.Sprite` See examples at [Piman's sprite tutorial](http://kai.vm.bytemark.co.uk/~piman/writing/sprite-tutorial.shtml)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just had to use sprite.rect.center = mousePos Again many thanks!